# What is the nounset equivalent in Makefiles?

Tags: gnu-make

`set -o nounset` in Bash is really useful, but I don't want to have to run that for every line in my Makefile. Is it possible to get the same effect with a *global* setting in a Makefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide global shell settings in `.SHELLFLAGS` variable [since GNU make 3.82](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS?id=33bda4008650c48816331c04022176f48c213fb3#n369). Like so:

```
$ cat Makefile
.SHELLFLAGS := -o nounset -c

all:
        echo "Foo is $${FOO}"

unset:
        set -o nounset; echo "Foo is $${FOO}"

make-resolved:
        echo "Foo is ${FOO}"
```

Output:

```
$ make all
echo "Foo is ${FOO}"
/bin/sh: FOO: unbound variable
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 127

$ make unset
set -o nounset; echo "Foo is ${FOO}"
/bin/sh: FOO: unbound variable
make: *** [Makefile:7: unset] Error 127
```

Without `.SHELLFLAGS` the first invocation succeeds:

```
$ make all .SHELLFLAGS=-c
echo "Foo is ${FOO}"
Foo is

$ make unset .SHELLFLAGS=-c
set -o nounset; echo "Foo is ${FOO}"
/bin/sh: FOO: unbound variable
make: *** [Makefile:7: unset] Error 127
```

Note that you need to escape `$` to have it actually resolved by shell, not make. The last target shows that make will resolve `${FOO}` and the shell will not complain:

```
$ make make-resolved
echo "Foo is "
Foo is
```

You can get a warning (not an error) from make in this situation as well [since GNU make 3.68](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS?id=33bda4008650c48816331c04022176f48c213fb3#n1200):

```
$ make --warn-undefined-variables make-resolved
Makefile:10: warning: undefined variable 'FOO'
echo "Foo is "
Foo is
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh how I long for a `--error-undefined-variables` flag to go with the existing `--warn-undefined-variables` one. An empty variable is always an error in my makefiles.

In the interim, for the more involved expansions I often use something like `$(call expand,var)` instead of plain `${var}` to catch speeling mistakes and the like.

```
expand = $(or ${$1},$(error [$1] is empty!))
```

Useful to check your hashes have the right keys.

```
codename<0.0.1> := Initial
codename<0.2.0> := Anniversary
codename<1.0.a> := Beta

codename := $(call expand,codename<${version}>)
```

etc.